# Haskell type vs. newtype with respect to type safety

Tags: haskell, types, type-systems

I know `newtype` is more often compared to `data` in Haskell, but I'm posing this comparison from more of a design point-of-view than as a technical problem.

In imperitive/OO languages, there is the anti-pattern "[primitive obsession](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/primitive-obsession)", where the prolific use of primitive types reduces the type-safety of a program and introduces accidentally interchangeability of same-typed values, otherwise intended for different purposes. For example, many things can be a String, but it would be nice if a compiler could know, statically, which we mean to be a name and which we mean to be the city in an address.

So, how often then, do Haskell programmers employ `newtype` to give type distinctions to otherwise primitive values? The use of `type` introduces an alias and gives a program's readability clearer semantics, but doesn't prevent accidentally interchanges of values. As I learn haskell I notice that the type system is as powerful as any I have come across. Therefore, I would think this is a natural and common practice, but I haven't seen much or any discussion of the use of `newtype` in this light.

Of course a lot of programmers do things differently, but is this at all common in haskell?

Comment: Hrm... looks like I can't mark more than one answer as accepted. I was hoping to somehow accept a reasonable representation of the differing opinions on this issue...

Comment: I have voted to re-open because it seems to me clear that the question _can_ be answered with facts and citations, as I did in my answer below, where I noted exactly how often `newtype` was used over `type` in a large program. It would be nice to have similar evidence from others, but that won't appear here if nobody can add another answer with that information.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The main uses for newtypes are:

1. For defining alternative instances for types.
2. Documentation.
3. Data/format correctness assurance.

I'm working on an application right now in which I use newtypes extensively. `newtypes` in Haskell are a purely compile-time concept. E.g. with unwrappers below, `unFilename (Filename "x")` compiled to the same code as "x". There is absolutely zero run-time hit. There is with `data` types. This makes it a very nice way to achieve the above listed goals.

```
-- | A file name (not a file path).
newtype Filename = Filename { unFilename :: String }
    deriving (Show,Eq)
```

I don't want to accidentally treat this as a file path. It's not a file path. It's the name of a conceptual file somewhere in the database.

It's very important for algorithms to refer to the right thing, newtypes help with this. It's also very important for security, for example, consider upload of files to a web application. I have these types:

```
-- | A sanitized (safe) filename.
newtype SanitizedFilename = 
  SanitizedFilename { unSafe :: String } deriving Show

-- | Unique, sanitized filename.
newtype UniqueFilename =
  UniqueFilename { unUnique :: SanitizedFilename } deriving Show

-- | An uploaded file.
data File = File {
   file_name     :: String         -- ^ Uploaded file.
  ,file_location :: UniqueFilename -- ^ Saved location.
  ,file_type     :: String         -- ^ File type.
  } deriving (Show)
```

Suppose I have this function which cleans a filename from a file that's been uploaded:

```
-- | Sanitize a filename for saving to upload directory.
sanitizeFilename :: String            -- ^ Arbitrary filename.
                 -> SanitizedFilename -- ^ Sanitized filename.
sanitizeFilename = SanitizedFilename . filter ok where 
  ok c = isDigit c || isLetter c || elem c "-_."
```

Now from that I generate a unique filename:

```
-- | Generate a unique filename.
uniqueFilename :: SanitizedFilename -- ^ Sanitized filename.
               -> IO UniqueFilename -- ^ Unique filename.
```

It's dangerous to generate a unique filename from an arbitrary filename, it should be sanitized first. Likewise, a unique filename is thus always safe by extension. I can save the file to disk now and put that filename in my database if I want to.

But it can also be annoying to have to wrap/unwrap a lot. In the long run, I see it as worth it especially for avoiding value mismatches. ViewPatterns help somewhat:

```
-- | Get the form fields for a form.
formFields :: ConferenceId -> Controller [Field]
formFields (unConferenceId -> cid) = getFields where
   ... code using cid ..
```

Maybe you'll say that unwrapping it in a function is a problem -- what if you pass `cid` to a function wrongly? Not an issue, all functions using a conference id will use the ConferenceId type. What emerges is a sort of function-to-function-level contract system that is forced at compile time. Pretty nice. So yeah I use it as often as I can, especially in big systems.

Comment: This is incredibly cool stuff Chris.  I just used this for a type class solution to Real World Haskell chapter 8 exercise 2 from the first set of exercises.  It asks to provide a way to select case-insensitive glob matching.  Thank you :)

Comment: How is the ViewPattern in the last example different from `(ConferenceID cid)`?

Comment: In my case I don't export the constructor because I don't want to create arbitrary values from any old integer, it should come from the database only. I can unwrap one safely and use that integer.

Answer (score 20):

I think this is mostly a matter of the situation.

Consider pathnames.  The standard prelude has "type FilePath = String" because, as a matter of convenience, you want to have access to all the string and list operations.  If you had "newtype FilePath = FilePath String" then you would need filePathLength, filePathMap and so on, or else you would forever be using conversion functions.

On the other hand, consider SQL queries.  SQL injection is a common security hole, so it makes sense to have something like

```
newtype Query = Query String
```

and then add extra functions that will convert a string into a query (or query fragment) by escaping quote characters, or fill in blanks in a template in the same way.  That way you can't accidentally convert a user parameter into a query without going through the quote escaping function.

Comment: In response to the file path example, the question is more in the context of design that you're doing, and less about what's already been designed where you don't have control. In the former situation, the consumer of your module/function/whatever won't see the code to get the primitive. In the latter situation, it's at worst the one call to get the primitive back out just before the call.

On the other hand, that's exactly why I asked: to get a sense of what different haskell programmers think about the design choice. Admittedly, I'm a person who leans towards the safety over convenience.

Comment: Like I said though, since I wanted to get a sense of diff. practices in haskell culture, your answer is still valuable. I'm not done here yet. :)

Comment: I understand that you are considering your own design practice: I just wanted to give a couple of practical examples.

The cost of saying "newtype FilePath" is in programmer time; the conversion functions are just to keep the type checker happy and have no implementation.  The main point is that if you are repeatedly converting in and out of your newtype then you have no real extra safety, just a lot of obfuscating function calls.  

So when designing a library you need to think about the application programmers point of view.

Answer (score 18):

For simple `X = Y` declarations, `type` is documentation; `newtype` is type checking; this is why `newtype` is compared to `data`.

I fairly frequently use `newtype` for just the purpose you describe: ensuring that something which is stored (and often manipulated) in the same way as another type is not confused with something else. In that way it works just as a slightly more efficient `data` declaration; there's no particular reason to chose one over the other. Note that with GHC's `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` extension, for either you can automatically derive classes such as `Num`, allowing your temperatures or yen to be added and subtracted just as you can with the `Int`s or whatever lies beneath them. One wants to be a little bit careful with this, however; typically one doesn't multiply a temperature by another temperature!

For an idea of how often these things are used, In one reasonably large project I'm working on right now, I have about 122 uses of `data`, 39 uses of `newtype`, and 96 uses of `type`.

But the ratio, as far as "simple" types are concerned, is a bit closer than that demonstrates, because 32 of those 96 uses of `type` are actually aliases for function types, such as

```
type PlotDataGen t = PlotSeries t -> [String]
```

You'll note two extra complexities here: first, it's actually a function type, not just a simple `X = Y` alias, and second that it's parameterized: `PlotDataGen` is a type constructor that I apply to another type to create a new type, such as `PlotDataGen (Int,Double)`. When you start doing this kind of thing, `type` is no longer just documentation, but is actually a function, though at the type level rather than the data level.

`newtype` is occasionally used where `type` can't be, such as where a recursive type definition is necessary, but I find this to be reasonably rare. So it looks like, on this particular project at least, about 40% of my "primitive" type definitions are `newtype`s and 60% are `type`s. Several of the `newtype` definitions used to be types, and were definitely converted for the exact reasons you mentioned.

So in short, yes, this is a frequent idiom.

Answer (score 10):

I think it is quite common to use `newtype` for type distinctions. In many cases this is because you want to give different type class instances, or to hide implementations, but simply wanting to protect against accidental conversions is also an obvious reason to do it.