# Difference between `data` and `newtype` in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, type-systems, newtype

What is the difference when I write this?

```
data Book = Book Int Int
```

versus

```
newtype Book = Book (Int, Int) -- "Book Int Int" is syntactically invalid
```

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649305/why-is-there-data-and-newtype-in-haskell

Comment: Also related: uses for newtype: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/991467/haskell-type-vs-newtype-with-respect-to-type-safety

Comment: Note that `newtype Book = Book Int Int` isn't valid. You can however, have `newtype Book = Book (Int, Int)` as noted by dons below.

Comment: In addition to @EdwardKMETT's comment I think `Book Int Int` is rather *semantically invalid* because `newtype` can only have *one* value constructor with *only one* field. `Book Int Int` has two fields.

Answer (score 295, accepted):

Great question!

There are several key differences.

**Representation**

- A `newtype` guarantees that your data will have exactly the same representation at runtime, as the type that you wrap.
- While `data` declares a brand new data structure at runtime.

So the key point here is that the construct for the `newtype` is guaranteed to be erased at compile time.

Examples:

- `data Book = Book Int Int`

[image: data]

- `newtype Book = Book (Int, Int)`

[image: newtype]

Note how it has exactly the same representation as a `(Int,Int)`, since the `Book` constructor is erased.

- `data Book = Book (Int, Int)`

[image: data tuple]

Has an additional `Book` constructor not present in the `newtype`.

- `data Book = Book {-# UNPACK #-}!Int {-# UNPACK #-}!Int`

[image]

No pointers! The two `Int` fields are unboxed word-sized fields in the `Book` constructor.

**Algebraic data types**

Because of this need to erase the constructor, a `newtype` only works when wrapping a data type with **a single constructor**. There's no notion of "algebraic" newtypes. That is, you can't write a newtype equivalent of, say,

```
data Maybe a = Nothing
             | Just a
```

since it has more than one constructor. Nor can you write

```
newtype Book = Book Int Int
```

**Strictness**

The fact that the constructor is erased leads to some very subtle differences in strictness between `data` and `newtype`. In particular, `data` introduces a type that is "lifted", meaning, essentially, that it has an additional way to evaluate to a bottom value. Since there's no additional constructor at runtime with `newtype`, this property doesn't hold.

That extra pointer in the `Book` to `(,)` constructor allows us to put a bottom value in.

As a result, `newtype` and `data` have slightly different strictness properties, as [explained in the Haskell wiki article](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Newtype#The_messy_bits).

**Unboxing**

It doesn't make sense to unbox the components of a `newtype`, since there's no constructor. While it is perfectly reasonable to write:

```
data T = T {-# UNPACK #-}!Int
```

yielding a runtime object with a `T` constructor, and an `Int#` component. You just get a bare `Int` with `newtype`.

---

*References*:

- ["Newtype" on the Haskell wiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Newtype)
- [Norman Ramsey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649305/why-is-there-data-and-newtype-in-haskell/2650051#2650051) about the strictness properties

Comment: I still don't think I'd miss something if there was no "newtype" in Haskell. The subtle differences add complexity to the language that don't seem worthwile to me...

Comment: The difference is very useful for performance reasons.  Since newtype constructors are erased at compile time, they don't impose the runtime performance penalty that a data constructor does.  But they still give you all the benefits of a completely distinct type and whatever abstractions you want to associate with it.  For instance, there are two different ways the list data type can form a monad.  One is built into the language, but if you wanted to use the other one, a newtype would be the way to go.

Comment: Great explanation! What I don't understand is if `newtype` is erased after compilation and runtime uses the same representation for old and new types, how can we still be able to define instances for both old and new type? How can runtime understand which instance to use?

Comment: @damluar All types are erased at runtime, they are all fully resolved at compile time, and during compilation `newtype` is obviously not yet erased.

Comment: @damlaur I once had the same question as you. When people say the types are erased, they omit to mention that one thing ISN'T erased, which is a memory word that is used for dictionary lookups to decide what instance method to use for a given piece of data. People argue that this word isn't a "type", which I think depends on your perspective, but there you go.

Comment: As an extension to the original question; in instances where `newtype` can be used, is there a benefit for using `data` instead? Should `newtype` be in every case that qualifies for it?

Comment: @mightybyte, why would one ever want to use `data SingleConstructorType = S T` instead of `newtype SingleConstructorType' = S' T`? When is the extra layer of distinct bottom state useful for a single-constructor, single-member data type?

Comment: @ASz I can't think of any reason (although there may still be one).  If my data type has a single field, I'd start out using a `newtype`.  Then if I needed to add more fields later, I'd switch it to `data`.

Comment: @ASz Additionally, if your data type is recursive, you can't use `newtype`. Like:
`data List a = Either () (a, List a)`

Answer (score 0):

They are different in semantics.

- `data` defines a GADT (product type, sum type, etc)
- `newtype` defines an isomorphism.

When you don't care about whether it's isomorphic, you should use `data`, even though it has only 1 field.

For example,

```hs
data Student = Student {
    age :: Int
}
```

If in this problem domain where `age` is the only infomation you have to process about a student, you should use `data` rather than `newtype`, because you never mean that a student should be isomorphic to an age.