# type vs data performance in haskell

Tags: haskell, types

I found answers explaining difference between `newtype` and `data` in Haskell. But if I have the following type synonym:

```
type Point = (Int,Int)
```

Would that be more efficient rather to use:

```
data Point = Pt (Int,Int) ?
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889696/difference-between-data-and-newtype-in-haskell, in particular the representation part.

Comment: I checked that question before putting this one. The other question is about different between `newtype` and `data` NOT between `type` and `data`

Comment: Wrapping the data constructor Pt with a pair (,) in `data Point = Pt (Int,Int)` is inefficient. You are better to use `data Point = Pt Int Int`. In some cases you might opt for strict Ints as well.

Comment: @stephen: and how does this compare to the type synonym?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `type` will be more efficient, as it incurs one less indirection than the `data` version.

Note that both are more inefficient than:

```
data Point = Point {-# UNPACK #-}!Int {-# UNPACK #-}!Int
```

as you can see from this earlier question on [data representations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889696/difference-between-data-and-newtype-in-haskell).

Comment: wonder if this is more efficient, why isn't it default in the language

Comment: Changes the semantics, and makes some programs unimplementable. Defaults /= Most Efficient. Instead, Most General.

Comment: With some exceptions (note `length` verses `genericLength`)

Comment: Am i right to say `data Point = Point {-# UNPACK #-}!(Int,Int)` that is single constructor is better than `data Point = Point {-# UNPACK #-}!Int {-# UNPACK #-}!Int`?

Comment: No, that's a worse representation, as the tuple is still a pair of pointers to Ints. See the data representation link above.

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

The Pt construction adds one word of overhead (in GHC) and the field (i.e. the pair) is stored as a pointer to a pair, adding one additional word, for a total of two words overhead (and an extra indirection to get to the values).

I recommend that you either use the type synonym or, better yet, define

```
data Point = Pt {-# UNPACK #-} !Int {-# UNPACK #-} !Int
```

This requires 4 words less than

```
type Point = (Int, Int)
```

and uses one less level of indirections (pointers).