# Strict single-constructor single-field data declaration vs. newtype

Tags: haskell

[Difference between `data` and `newtype` in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889696/difference-between-data-and-newtype-in-haskell) and a couple other questions address the general differences between data and newtype. My question is a very specific one. If `G` is some type, is there any difference between

`data T = T !G`

and

`newtype T = T G`?

They appear to have the same strictness properties, and I don't see why the compiler would have any reason to compile them differently, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Your question is answered [on the wiki](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Newtype).

Comment: what does `!` stand for in `!G`?

Answer (score 3):

The major difference is in how it's gonna get compiled. All `data` declarations [introduce memory overhead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3256825/485115), while `newtype` don't.

Here's an output of a memory footprint measurement library.

```
import GHC.DataSize

data A = A !Int
newtype B = B Int

main = do
  print =<< (recursiveSize $! A 1)
  print =<< (recursiveSize $! B 1)
  print =<< (recursiveSize $! 1)
```

output:

```
32
16
16
```

Another difference is mentioned by Shachaf in the first comment.

Comment: There's a difference in semantics: `case undefined of A _ -> ()` is `undefined`; `case undefined of B _ -> ()` is `()`.

Comment: @schachaf Wow, that's a case I didn't know about. Thanks.

Comment: @shachaf, I think you hit the nail on the head. I guess pattern matching on a newtype is a no-op, whereas pattern matching on a strict data type is a force.

Comment: what does `!` stand for in `!Int`?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp It declares that the field should be evaluated strictly instead of lazily (the default). In case of the `newtype` wrapper the wrapped typed can only be strict, so there's no bang required there.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to answer a slightly different question: "does `newtype` add any *semantic* functionality to Haskell?".  I believe the answer is "no".

Suppose we have `data Td = Td !G` and `newtype Tn = Tn G`.  Then

- `Td` and `Tn` have exactly the same inhabitants, i.e. the inhabitants of `G`
- When forced to WHNF both behave in the same way: the `g` they "contain" is forced
- They differ in how they interact with `case` but this is only  syntactic.  There is a direct correspondance between the two versions.

The following table explains how a `newtype` `Tn` can be replaced by a `data` `Td` in a `case` statement.  There's also a translation back the other way.

```
Tn                                    Td

case tn of _ -> ...                   case td of _ -> ...
case tn of Tn _ -> ...

case tn of Tn x -> ... x ...          let x1 = case tn of Td x -> x in ... x1 ...

case tn of x -> ... x ...             case td of x -> ... x ...

case tn of Tn x -> x `seq` ...        case td of Td _ -> ...         

case tn of Tn x -> x `seq` ... x ...  case td of Td x -> ... x ...
```

So semantically speaking I believe Haskell could have avoided adding `newtype`.  Syntactically speaking newtype maybe makes `case` statements a less awkward, that's all.

Comment: Td has both `bottom` and `T bottom`, whereas `Tn` only has `T bottom`.

Comment: In `Td`, `bottom` and `Td bottom` are indistinguishable.

Comment: `case td of Td _ -> "whee"`

Comment: @SebastianRedl: What are you trying to say?  Note here that `G` is a strict data field, so `case td of Td _` forces it.