# make network instance of vectorSpace

Tags: haskell

This is a follow up question to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38510132/make-matrix-double-vector-double-an-instance-of-num). Somebody suggested there that it would make more sense to make the type network an instance of vectorSpace.

```
newtype Network = Network [( Matrix Double, Vector Double)]

instance AdditiveGroup Network where
  (Network n1) ^+^ (Network n2) = Network $ zipWith (\(m,v) (n,w) -> (m+n,v+w)) n1 n2
  (Network n1) ^-^ (Network n2) = Network $ zipWith (\(m,v) (n,w) -> (m-n,v-w)) n1 n2

instance VectorSpace Network where
  type Scalar Network = Double
  lambda *^ (Network n) = Network $ map (\ (m,v) -> (lambda*m,lambda*v)) n
```

But when I try to compile I get an error saying that i wrote an illegal instance for 'Scalar'.
Could somebody explain me what I did wrong?

Comment: You should include the error message in the future. It makes it a lot easier and faster to figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error comes from the fact that being able to declare `type` in a class and instance is not standard Haskell, it is part of the [type families extension](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/Type_families#Associated_type_instances_2). Getting rid of that error isn't tough, you just have to add the following language pragma at the top of your file:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
```

However, then you might have a problem with the fact that you haven't defined `zeroV` or `negateV` in your `AdditiveGroup` instance. I'm not sure how you will define those... You may even get away without defining them (you'll get warnings though, and something may crash at runtime).