# Why can't the compiler handle newtype for us in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I understand that `newtype` erases the type constructor at compile time as an optimization, so that `newtype Foo = Foo Int` results in just an `Int`. In other words, I am not asking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5889696/27779). My question is not about what `newtype` does.

Instead, I'm trying to understand why the compiler can't simply apply this optimization itself when it sees a single-value `data` constructor. When I use `hlint`, it's smart enough to tell me that a single-value `data` constructor should be a `newtype`. (I never make this mistake, but tried it out to see what would happen. My suspicions were confirmed.)

One objection could be that without `newtype`, we couldn't use `GeneralizedNewTypeDeriving` and other such extensions. But that's easily solved. If we say…

```hs
data Foo m a b = Foo a (m b) deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad)
```

The compiler can just barf and tell us of our folly.

Why do we need `newtype` when the compiler can always figure it out for itself?

Comment: My own personal guess is that `newtype` has semantic value. It tells us something about the developers intent. "I would like to wrap this type, perhaps hide some of its functionality, and enhance it in some other way."

Comment: `newtype` is slightly decreases laziness, which can sometimes be a desired effect, since there is no real data constructor.

Comment: Right. Like I said, I understand what it does. What I don't understand is why the compiler can't just figure out when to apply this optimization.

Comment: In other words, if I say `data Foo a = Foo a`, the compiler *knows* it can transform this into `newtype Foo a = Foo a`. It can always do this with single-value data constructors, so why not just make that implicit and get rid of `newtype`?

Comment: exactly because decreased laziness is not per se a desired side-effect. That depends on the application.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It seems plausible that `newtype` started out mostly as a programmer-supplied annotation to perform an optimization that compilers were too stupid to figure out on their own, sort of like the `register` keyword in C.

However, in Haskell, `newtype` isn't just an advisory annotation for the compiler; it actually has semantic consequences.  The types:

```
newtype Foo = Foo Int
data Bar = Bar Int
```

declare two non-isomorphic types.  Specifically, `Foo undefined` and `undefined :: Foo` are equivalent while `Bar undefined` and `undefined :: Bar` are not, with the result that:

```
Foo undefined `seq` "not okay"    -- is an exception
Bar undefined `seq` "okay"        -- is "okay"
```

and

```
case undefined of Foo n -> "okay"       -- is okay
case undefined of Bar n -> "not okay"   -- is an exception
```

As others have noted, if you make the `data` field strict:

```
data Baz = Baz !Int
```

and take care to only use irrefutable pattern matches, then `Baz` acts just like the `newtype Foo`:

```
Baz undefined `seq` "not okay"         -- exception, like Foo
case undefined of ~(Baz n) -> "okay"   -- is "okay", like Foo
```

In other words, if my grandmother had wheels, she'd be a bike!

So, why can't the compiler simply apply this optimization itself when it sees a single-value data constructor?  Well, it can't perform this optimization *in general* without changing the semantics of a program, so it needs to first prove that the semantics are unchanged if a particular arbitrary, one-constructor, one-field `data` type is made strict in its field and matched irrefutably instead of strictly.  Since this depends on how values of the type are actually used, this can be hard to do for data types exported by a module, especially at function call boundaries, but the existing optimization mechanisms for specialization, inlining, strictness analysis, and unboxing often perform equivalent optimizations in chunks of self-contained code, so you may get the benefits of a `newtype` even when you use a `data` type by accident.  In general, though, it seems to be too hard a problem for the compiler to solve, so the burden of remembering to `newtype` things is left on the programmer.

This leads to the obvious question -- *why* can't we change the semantics so they're equivalent; why are the semantics of `newtype` and `data` different in the first place?

Well, the reason for the `newtype` semantics seems pretty obvious.  As a result of the nature of the `newtype` optimization (erasure of the type and constructor at compile time), it becomes impossible -- or at the very least exceedingly difficulty -- to separately represent `Foo undefined` and `undefined :: Foo` at compile time which explains the equivalence of these two values.  Consequently, irrefutable matching is an obvious further optimization when there's only one possible constructor **and** there's no possibility that that constructor isn't present (or at least no possibility of distinguishing between presence and absence of the constructor, because the only case where this could happen is in distinguishing between `Foo undefined` and `undefined :: Foo`, which we've already said can't be distinguished in compiled code).

The reason for the semantics of a one-constructor, one-field `data` type (in the absence of strictness annotations and irrefutable matches) is maybe less obvious.  However, these semantics are entirely consistent with data types having constructor and/or field counts other than one, while the `newtype` semantics would introduce an arbitrary inconsistency between this one special case of a `data` type and all others.

Because of this historical distinction between `data` and `newtype` types, a number of subsequent extensions have treated them differently, further entrenching different semantics.  You mention `GeneralizedNewTypeDeriving` which works on `newtype`s but not one-constructor, one-field `data` types.  There are further differences in calculation of representational equivalence used for safe coercions (i.e., `Data.Coerce`) and `DerivingVia`, the use of existential quantification or more general GADTs, the `UNPACK` pragma, etc.  There are also some differences in the way types are represented in generics, though now that I look at them more carefully, they seem pretty superficial.

Even if `newtype`s were an unnecessary historical mistake that could have been replaced by special-casing certain `data` types, it's a little late to put the genie back in the bottle.

Besides, `newtype`s don't really strike me as unnecessary duplication of an existing facility.  To me, `data` and `newtype` types are conceptually quite different.  A `data` type is an algebraic, sum-of-products type, and it's just coincidence that a particular special case of algebraic types happens to have one constructor and one field and so ends up being (nearly) isomorphic to the field type.  In contrast, a `newtype` is intended from the start to be an isomorphism of an existing type, basically a type alias with an extra wrapper to distinguish it at the type level and allow us to pass around a separate type constructor, attach instances, and so on.

Comment: I don't think it's nearly as hard as you suggest. `data Bar a = Bar !a` can be translated to `newtype Bar a = Bar_ a` with `pattern Bar :: a -> Bar a; pattern Bar a <- Bar_ !a where Bar = Bar_`. Obviously, pattern synonyms are new, but the compiler's always pulled similar-enough tricks for worker-wrapper.

Answer (score 19):

This is an excellent question. Semantically,

```
newtype Foo = Foo Int
```

is identical to

```
data Foo' = Foo !Int
```

except that pattern matching on the former is lazy and on the latter is strict. So a compiler certainly *could* compile them the same, and adjust the compilation of pattern matching to keep the semantics right.

For a type like you've described, that optimization isn't really all that critical in practice, because users can just use `newtype` and sprinkle in `seq`s or bang patterns as needed. Where it would get a lot more useful is for existentially quantified types and GADTs. That is, we'd like to get the more compact representation for types like

```
data Baz a b where
  Baz :: !a -> Baz a Bool

data Quux where
  Quux :: !a -> Quux
```

But GHC doesn't currently offer any such optimization, and doing so would be somewhat trickier in these contexts.

Answer (score 10):

> Why do we need `newtype` when the compiler can always figure it out for itself?

It can’t. `data` and `newtype` have different semantics: `data` adds an additional level of indirection, while `newtype` has exactly the same representation as its wrapped type, and always uses lazy pattern matching, while you choose whether to make `data` lazy or strict with strictness annotation (`!` or pragmas like `StrictData`).

Likewise, a compiler doesn’t always know *for certain* when `data` can be replaced with `newtype`. *Strictness analysis* allows it to conservatively determine when it may remove unnecessary laziness around things that will always be evaluated; in this case it can effectively remove the `data` wrapper *locally*. GHC does something similar when removing extra boxing & unboxing in a chain of operations on a boxed numeric type like `Int`, so it can do most of the calculations on the more efficient unboxed `Int#`. But in general (that is, without global optimisation) it *can’t know* whether some code is relying on that thunk’s being there.

So HLint offers this as a suggestion because *usually* you don’t need the “extra” wrapper at runtime, but other times it’s essential. The advice is just that: advice.

Comment: There is nothing that inherently prevents a `data` with a single strict field to be compiled with no indirection, is there? A language where what we know today as a newtype (with its `Coercible` instance) were just a special case of `data` seems completely plausible with the added benefit of having one fewer keyword, so the more interesting question, which I think is what OP is asking, is why that alternative design was not chosen?

Comment: In particular, the example of `Int#` seems irrelevant. `newtype` wraps already boxed types, or more generally, it is about not changing representation.

Comment: Given the claim that the runtime wrapper is essential sometimes, is it possible for you to provide a toy demo example?

Comment: @Li-yaoXia Take `data D = D !Int; newtype N = N Int`. Then `case D undefined of D _ -> ()` is `undefined` but `case N undefined of N _ -> ()` is `()`.

Comment: I know these are different, but there is a semantic-preserving translation from "Haskell with newtypes" to "Haskell without newtypes" (modulo changing the target of `Coercible`). Whenever you write `\(N x) -> f x`  you could equivalently write `\ ~(D x) -> f x`.

Comment: @Li-yaoXia "… why that alternative design was not chosen?" This is exactly what I want to know. As K. A. Buhr pointed out in his answer, it may have arisen as an optimization early compilers were too stupid to figure out, and then became entrenched as differences arose. However, someone designing a Haskell-ish language from scratch could chose to make it an implicit optimization. (The designer of Purescript decided to keep it, interestingly.)