# newtype v. data for Monoid Wrappers?

Tags: haskell

[Typeclassopedia](https://wiki.haskell.org/Typeclassopedia#Monoid) comments on Monoids:

```
since we can’t have two instances for the same type, 
 Data.Monoid provides two newtype wrappers, Sum and Product, 
  with appropriate Monoid instances.
> getSum (mconcat . map Sum $ [1..5])
15
> getProduct (mconcat . map Product $ [1..5])
120
```

Why is a `newtype` wrapper, rather than `data`, used?

Note - I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22080564/whats-the-practical-value-of-all-those-newtype-wrappers-in-data-monoid) useful, but I didn't find my answer.

Comment: "I found this question useful, but I didn't find my answer." -- How so?

Comment: in particular, I'm curious about why `newtype` gets used over `data`. I'm not arguing for the latter, but that's my question.

Comment: What about [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649305/why-is-there-data-and-newtype-in-haskell)?

Comment: Or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889696/difference-between-data-and-newtype-in-haskell)?

Comment: Or what about [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/991467/haskell-type-vs-newtype-with-respect-to-type-safety)?